# Failed to instantiate JaxbAnnotationIntrospector

Tags: web-services, rest

I am trying to run this example of REST from www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

But I am always getting this error.

[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector:173'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:173)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:609)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:171)
    ... 16 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:173)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:609)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate JaxbAnnotationIntrospector: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:171)
    ... 16 more

Can anyone please help me with it. I have the following jars in my classpath -